# c# complex and large xml loading

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have some problems parsing huge xml in c#, mostly because I returned from apex to c# after a long time. So far I cant get working even this

```
 private void read_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XElement xmlDoc = XElement.Load(@"D:\\AOI\\Samples\\Error\\60A84130868D_20180428035150_AOI-mek1.xml");
        var loaded_File =
                from fileInfo in xmlDoc.Descendants("result_file")

                select new File
                {

                    filename = fileInfo.Element("designator").Value,
                    supplier = fileInfo.Element("supplier").Value,
                    date_created = fileInfo.Element("date").Value,
                    station_ID = fileInfo.Element("station_ID").Value,
                    operator_ID = fileInfo.Element("operator_ID").Value,
                    program = fileInfo.Element("program").Value,
                    side_variant = fileInfo.Element("side_variant").Value
                };
        foreach(var item in loaded_File) { 
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Xml file looks as follows with multiple good_no and error_no, can someone navigate me how to load the file properly? I need it afterwards to insert it into database, but that should be just fine.

```
<result_file>
  <filename>60Axxxxxek1</filename>
  <supplier>Maxxxxz</supplier>
  <date>20xxxx5150</date>
  <station_ID>Axxxx1</station_ID>
  <operator_ID></operator_ID>
  <program>Xxxx01</program>
  <side_variant>A</side_variant>
  <pcbs_in_panel>0</pcbs_in_panel>
  <serial>60xxxxxx8D</serial>
  <status>GOOD</status>
  <starttime>20180xxxxxx150</starttime>
  <lot_no></lot_no>
  <info>
    <window_no>354</window_no>
    <packs_no>343</packs_no>
    <error_total>1</error_total>
    <error_conf>0</error_conf>
    <inspection_time>5</inspection_time>
    <panel_image>AOxxxxx_A.jpg</panel_image>
    <panel_image_location>x:\xml</panel_image_location>
    <ng_image_location>x:\xml\Xxxxx0428</ng_image_location>
    <repaired>0</repaired>
  </info>
  <errors>
    <error_no name="1">
      <designator></designator>
      <pin></pin>
      <stamp_name>Bridge:Short</stamp_name>
      <package_name></package_name>
      <errortype>-</errortype>
      <error_contents></error_contents>
      <pcb_no></pcb_no>
      <feeder_no></feeder_no>
      <pos_x>8760</pos_x>
      <pos_y>4600</pos_y>
      <window>-313</window>
      <ng_message></ng_message>
      <comment>(* *){Bridge:Short}</comment>
      <ng_image>Xxxxxx13.jpg</ng_image>
    </error_no>
  </errors>
  <goods>
    <good_no name="1">
      <designator>Ixxx1</designator>
      <pin>Ixxx1</pin>
      <stamp_name>Ixxxxrat</stamp_name>
      <package_name>Ixxxx1</package_name>
      <pcb_no></pcb_no>
      <feeder_no></feeder_no>
      <pos_x>3082</pos_x>
      <pos_y>3202</pos_y>
      <window>+1</window>
      <comment>(* *){Ixxxxat}</comment>
    </good_no>
   </goods>
  </result_file>
```

Thanks for advices.

EDIT:
I have also prepared classes for that

```
public class File
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string filename { get; set; }
        public string supplier { get; set; }
        public string date_created { get; set; }
        public string station_ID { get; set; }
        public string operator_ID { get; set; }
        public string program { get; set; }
        public string side_variant { get; set; }
        public string pcbs_in_panel { get; set; }
        public string serial { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string starttime { get; set; }
        public string lot_no { get; set; }
        public string window_no { get; set; }
        public string packs_no { get; set; }
        public string error_total { get; set; }
        public string error_conf { get; set; }
        public string inspection_time { get; set; }
        public string panel_image { get; set; }
        public string panel_image_location { get; set; }
        public string ng_image_location { get; set; }
        public string repaired { get; set; }
        public List<Good> Goods = new List<Good>();
        public List<Error> Errors = new List<Error>();
    }
    public class Good
    {
        public List<Good_no> Good_ones = new List<Good_no>();
    }
    public class Error
    {
        public List<Error_no> Error_ones = new List<Error_no>();
    }
    public class Good_no
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string designator { get; set; }
        public string pin { get; set; }
        public string stamp_name { get; set; }
        public string package_name { get; set; }
        public string pcb_no { get; set; }
        public string feeder_no { get; set; }
        public string pos_x { get; set; }
        public string pos_y { get; set; }
        public string window { get; set; }
        public string comment { get; set; }
    }
    public class Error_no
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string designator { get; set; }
        public string pin { get; set; }
        public string stamp_name { get; set; }
        public string package_name { get; set; }
        public string errortype { get; set; }
        public string error_contents { get; set; }
        public string pcb_no { get; set; }
        public string feeder_no { get; set; }
        public string pos_x { get; set; }
        public string pos_y { get; set; }
        public string window { get; set; }
        public string ng_message { get; set; }
        public string comment { get; set; }
        public string ng_image { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I cant get it written into debug, the foreach does not work, like its null, without any exception. So I dont know if it is loaded or not. Simply I cant call it back

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] that we could copy and paste into a console app to repro the issue.

Comment: What is missing? I did provide the current and only code, all classes included and sample of xml used. Only info missing is that it is form application and all the code is happening in button click. Simply when I click the button, then no error comes out, but the foreach into debug doesnt work like that (works when item.tostring is replaced with normal string

Comment: Is it a real xml? Does it have namespaces?

Comment: Don't tell us the file is "huge". If the size is relevant at all, then we need numbers. For some people "huge" means 1Mb, for others it means 1Tb - that's a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simplify the class structure:

```
public class File
{
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string Supplier { get; set; }
    // ...
    public List<Good> Goods { get; set; }
    public List<Error> Errors { get; set; }
}
public class Good
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Designator { get; set; }
    public string Pin { get; set; }
    // ...
}
public class Error
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Designator { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Then the reading would look like this:

```
var xmlDoc = XElement.Load("test.xml");

var loadedFile = new File
{
    Filename = xmlDoc.Element("filename").Value,
    Supplier = xmlDoc.Element("supplier").Value,
    // ...
    Goods = (from good in xmlDoc.Element("goods").Elements("good_no")
             select new Good
             {
                 Name = good.Attribute("name").Value,
                 Designator = good.Element("designator").Value,
                 Pin = good.Element("pin").Value
                 // ...
             })
             .ToList()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the XML-File, I recommmend you to deserialize the XML-files.
For this, your class-definition isn't complete. In Visual Studio is a tool, called xsd.exe. With this tool you can transform your XML-File first in a XSD-Schema. From the XSD-Schema you can generate the required classes.

To transform to XSD-Schema: xsd.exe {Filename.xml}

To transform to C#-Classes: xsd.exe /c {Filename.xsd}

XSD have many more options (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.120).aspx)

If you have the correct classes you can read the XML-File with the XMLSerializer (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.110).aspx)